# Populating Generic JComboBox with Enum

Tags: java, swing, enums, jcombobox

I have a JPanel with multiple JComboBoxes for user input. Each JComboBox is instantiated with the values of an enum. There are several of these JComboBoxes, so I want to have a method to instantiate and set up each one. For example:

```
private JComboBox card_type_box = this.createCombo(CardType.values());

...   

private JComboBox createCombo(CardType[] card_types)
{
  final JComboBox combo = new JComboBox(card_types);
  combo.setSelectedIndex(0);
  combo.addActionListener(this);
  ...
  return combo;
}
```

The issue with this method is that it only accepts enums of type CardType. Is it possible to have this method accept an arbitrary enum to create a new JComboBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using something like (under Java 7)...

```
private <E extends Enum> JComboBox<E> createCombo(E[] values) {
    final JComboBox<E> combo = new JComboBox(values);
```

or

```
private <E extends Enum> JComboBox createCombo(E[] values) {
    final JComboBox combo = new JComboBox(values);
```

Under Java 6, for example...

Comment: You cannot parameterize JComboBox with generic arguments <E>, but otherwise this works. Thanks.

Comment: @TroySquillaci Yes you can, but you need to be using Java 7 ;)

Comment: @TroySquillaci Thanks for neat idea.  Must remember this in the future ;)